# Logo link issues with browser width lower than 992px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am experiencing issues with the main logo link when the browser width is lower than 992px. It's working fine above this width.

Link is [www.bestkennels.ie](http://www.bestkennels.ie) . If you visit any page and click the logo it should bring you back to the homepage. It seems only the top part of the logo is clickable. If i inspect in the dev tools i dont see any logo height issues.

I've tested in the latest Mac versions of Chrome and Firefox

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the issue, as well as the related code.

Comment: use a div with clearfix between  `<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2"><a class="show" href="/"></div>` and `<div class="col-md-10">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `div#navbar` is covering part of your clickable logo.  Its height should not be so large.  You should use a `margin-top` to properly separate the elements instead.

Comment: Thanks, yes this makes sense. Seems it's overlapping when the browser width is narrower. Thanks again.

Comment: If you're happy with my answer, may I recommend that you please mark it as the correct one?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure, i just had to wait 10 mins before it would let me :-)